# oAuth long term access for consumers

Tags: oauth

From a Service Provider standpoint, how would you go about 'permanent' access to data? without needing to re-authenticate with the server for an access key, instead just allowing the user to allow the service to access their data until it's removed from the list of allowed consumers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the OAuth specification that users must be able to revoke access whenever they want.

Comment: I'm not looking for permanent access the user can't revoke, I'm just confused as to how to handle long-term access to users data (as long as they are permitting of course)

Comment: You would simply store the access key and access token against that user. For other services such as twitter you would also need to store the verifier pin.

Answer (score 0):

When the user initially authenticates, give the client a [refresh token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5):

> Refresh tokens are credentials used to obtain access tokens.  Refresh tokens are issued to the client by the authorization server and are used to obtain a new access token when the current access token becomes invalid or expires...